# Do Blazor server applications have an event I can handle when the user first logs in?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side application that is using Azure AD authentication. I would like to get some data about the current user from a database or web API and cache it when they first log in and then be able to use it during the session without fetching from the source every time it's needed.

I am unclear where to put this or if there is even an event I can add a handler for.

Are there any Blazor life cycle or other events where this can be done reliably?

## Update

I found that the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` method has an optional overload where events can be connected.

```
// Azure AD authentication settings....
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated += OnTokenValidatedFuncAsync;

    });
```

Then the `OnTokenValidatedFuncAsync` handler in `StartUp.cs` is:

```
private async Task OnTokenValidatedFuncAsync(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    var userName = context.Principal.Identity.Name;

    await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This returns name of the user that just connected and appears to be the event that I am looking for.

Now the problem is that I need to access the DI container to update an instance of a user object that will store the settings I plan to retrieve. I've tried a few options but I'm having trouble accessing the DI container from here. I attempted to use the [FromServices] attribute and inject the object but that does not work in this event handler. How can I access the DI container in this code?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I'm struggling with it too :)

Comment: No, I couldn't ever find a way to access the container. I can't recall exactly where this ended up and I left the project shortly after this post. I hope you can solve it and post an update. Blazor has had several version updates since then. Hopefully there's a better option now.